# Is it okay to encrypt server-side when using HTTPS?

Tags: encryption, https, server, client, tls1.2

I am creating a messaging service for an app I'm developing. Because of the nature of the messages, it is important not only to verify users, but also verify what conversation the message belongs to. So right now I create a public/private key pair for each conversation and use it to encrypt/decrypt the messages. Basically when a user is logged in, they have access to the key pairs of the conversations they belong to, but those key pairs only work for that particular conversation. This allows access to be granted/denied to particular conversations while keeping other conversations between those same parties intact. Right now the data flow is as follows:

Send:

message sent to server => message encrypted based on user's public key and signed using secret key => encrypted message saved to database

Receive:

server receives message from database => server verifies signature using public key and decrypts message using secret key => decrypted message sent to client

All the encryption/decryption on the server is dependent upon the user's JWT token being authenticated.

I have two main questions: 1.) Is it okay to encrypt on the server since the communication between it and the client is using TLS? 2.) Should the keys be stored on the server or in the database?

Also, if this method is insecure, incorrect, or flat out just dumb please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your method doesn't make all that much sense... If the server is able to decrypt, then you already trust the server?  If this is the case, all the crypto on top of this is superfluous.  Let the server manage authentication/exchange of messages and simply ensure everything uses HTTPS.

Comment: Firstly, my question is can I trust the server? Are the messages actually secure when they're sent over TLS? Secondly I'm trying to make sure that data sent to the database is encrypted. And not in the sense that the database has encrypted it, but in the sense that if I need to give someone access to the database, they wouldn't be able to read the messages, similar to how passwords are encrypted before they are sent to the database. Which is also why I would prefer to keep the keys on the server, but I don't know if this is a good practice or not.

Comment: First, yes, TLS is arguably the best transport security protocol there is, and the messages are definitely secure provided you use a modern cipher suite.  TLS is definitely not your weakpoint in this.  I think you might benefit from clearly defining your threat model.  What, exactly, are you trying to defend yourself from?  A database breach?  Or an API server breach?

Comment: I'm not a security expert by any means, but I'm trying to prevent messages from being read by someone not in the conversation. Now if the database is breached, I have more than just these messages to be worried about. So my main concern on that side is someone with access to the database being able to read the messages. And I obviously don't want a server breach, but that is not the goal of this particular security measure. I apologize for being so naive, this is a new area for me.

Comment: In general though, I read a lot about end-to-end encryption, which seems to involve decrypting on the client-side, but I'm not sure what exactly this is trying to prevent

Comment: End-to-end encryption pretty much means that the messages are encrypted and decrypted client-side and no where else.  It's an excellent tool but also incredibly difficult to implement.  Since your main concern is to protect your data at rest, I'd simply just use symmetric encryption in your API server to encrypt/decrypt the data as it is inserted/retrieved from the database.  Then use TLS to get it to and from the client and you are sorted.  The only vulnerability here is your API server, but there are other means you can take to ensure that your server is safe.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Is there any particular direction you could point me in to secure the API server?

Comment: Don't allow root login, always use a sudo user instead.  Only allow access to that sudo user.  Ensure that the sudo user can only login with an SSH private key and not a password.  Configure your firewall properly.  Mostly sysadmin stuff.

Comment: Okay, yea I already removed root login and only use SSH to login. I'll look into the firewall settings to see what I can do there. Thanks again for all the help.